# Determine which column contains the maximum sum of its elements

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to know, how to find out which column in the 2D-array has got the largest sum. How would I approach this?

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] array = {
                { 132, 154, 118 },
                { 355, 101,  50 },
                { 432, 143, 365 },
                { 462, 234, 185 }
        };
    }
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Is there a specific problem you are facing?

Comment: Definitely seems like homework.  If you haven't attempted, then look at for each loops if index doesn't matter.  Regular for loops if they do.  You can try IntStream, but that might be overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with a nested for loop

```
int maxCol = 0;
int valOfMaxCol = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
      sum += array[j][i];
    }
    if(sum > valOfMaxCol){
        valOfMaxCol = sum;
        maxCol = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("Max Col is " + (maxCol + 1) + " with the value " + valOfMaxCol);
```